# vuetable-2 input en v-server-table no respeta el paginado

Tags: vue.js

le he estado dando vueltas a esto y no he encontrado la solución, lo bueno es que hoy por la cantidad de filas no es ningún problema, pero en un futuro no muy lejano lo sera....

Resulta que tengo un modal en VueJs con una tabla, donde le agrego una columna con un input numerico, par a declarar un numero X, en resumen es algo así:

```
<v-server-table url="productos-listado" :columns="colDeclararProductos" :options="optDeclararProductos">
      <p class="text-center" slot="Unidades" slot-scope="props">
        <b-form-input type="number" :id="'Q_'+props.row.sku" v-model="declarado[props.row.sku]"></b-form-input>
      </p>
    </v-server-table>
```

Se ve bien, aparecen las columnas sku, nombre y el input que agregamos con nombre "Unidades" pero al momento de ingresar un numero en uno de esos input, no me modifica el array que tengo declarado en data() como:

```
declarado:[]
```

Ni tampoco al cambiar de pagina se trae el valor, quedando el input con el numero ingresado, en la misma posición, por ejemplo si en la fila 1 de la paginación 1 de la tabla pongo 100, al cambiar de pagina, los datos cambian, el problema que siendo en la fila 1 de la pagina 2 otro dato, el input se queda con los 100, y pasa en todas las paginas, para todas las filas.

Alguna idea para hacerlo con v-server-table??? o tengo que pasar todo a v-client-table?????

Como siempre gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que tenia el scope en otra etiqueta, así sí funciona :D

```
<v-server-table url="productos-listado" :columns="colDeclararProductos" :options="optDeclararProductos">
          <b-form-input slot="Unidades" slot-scope="props" min="0" type="number" v-model="arrayDeclarado[props.row.sku]"></b-form-input>
        </v-server-table>
```